# XML deserialization: object has default values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I've got a strange behaviour with my XML serializer.
After reading an XML and deserializing it into an object, all properties are set to it's default values and not to the values declared in the xml file.
The serializer doesn't throw an exception and runs properly. The xml file is properly formed and fits to the class structure.
Anyone an idea how that can be, or how I could get to the source of the problem?
Thank you

edit:
I didn't tell you the whole story. The thing is, the XML which I get is from another component. I was able to deserialize the XML file and now I got a diffrent format. Since the file has about 3000 lines I can't post the whole code. But here's the difference:
deserializable:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<rootElem xmlns:cfg="namespace1" xmlns:office="namespace2" xmlns="namespace3">`
  `<Prop1 xmlns="">6</Prop1>`
  `<Prop2 xmlns="">string</Prop2>`
`</rootElem>`

not deserializable

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
`<rootElem xmlns:cfg="namespace1" xmlns:office="namespace2" xmlns="namespace3">`
  `<Prop1>6</Prop1>`
  `<Prop2>string</Prop2>`
`</rootElem>`

I don't really understand why I can unmarshal the first example due to the xmlns tag inside **each** element and why I can't unmarshal the second one...

***edit2:*** just realized that just the top level elements got these strange xmlns="" attributes. But the C# class declaration is not different from all other classes...that's weird.

The C# class is like this:

```
using namespace1;

namespace namespace3
{
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="namespace3")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="namespace3", IsNullable=true)]
  public partial class rootElem: BaseObject
  {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int Prop1
    {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to give more information, preferably relevant code snippets with which you are deserializing.

Comment: @ipavlic updated the question and added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concrete example (both c# ad xml) would go a very long way here. Most likely one of:

- the names aren't an exact (case-sensitive) match between the xml and the c# (allowing for name overrides via attributes etc)
- there is a mixup between xml attributes / elements
- there is a difference in the xml namespaces (typically, present in the xml and missing in the c#)

---

With your edit, it becomes clearer. Xml namespaces are **very** significant; `<foo xmlns="abc"/>` and `<foo/>` are completely unrelated. Further, xml namespaces are **inherited**, so in:

```
<rootElem xmlns:cfg="namespace1" xmlns:office="namespace2" xmlns="namespace3">
<Prop1>6</Prop1>
<Prop2>string</Prop2>
</rootElem>
```

it is the case that `Prop1` and `Prop2` are in the `namespace3` namespace that they inherit from their parent. To make it absolutely clear to the c# that you want those to be in the child namespace (rather than the empty namespace), **tell it**:

```
[Serializable]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(Namespace = Namespace3)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = Namespace3, IsNullable = true)]
public partial class rootElem
{
    private const string Namespace3 = "namespace3"; // to avoid repetition

    [XmlElement(Namespace = Namespace3)]
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I updated my question, so I guess it has something to do with the xml syntax, since the c# classes nor the schema has been changed...

Comment: @derape this is actually the 3rd bullet; will edit to add more

Comment: do you think that this is the problem and that I will have to declare it explicitly? Because the classes are generated from the XSD and I would need to adapt the generation...

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I was able to find the problem. I still do not understand why the serializer behaves the way it does.
As far was I understood the decleration of namespaces you have to define the "xmlns" attribute without a prefix to set the default namespace ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)). As stated in my question it was defined (besides to other namespaces):

```
<rootElem xmlns:cfg="namespace1" xmlns:office="namespace2" xmlns="namespace3">
```

Since all direct children of the root element had the xmlns attribute (again) declared, my interpretation is that the default namespace couldn't be found.
So what I did was to explicity define a namespace for the root element so that the root element was generated like that:

```
<root:rootElem xmlns:cfg="namespace1" xmlns:office="namespace2" xmlns:root="namespace3">
```

And voila, the xml was generated properly (the xmlns attribute was removed from the direct children) and the serializer was able to read the data.
But still some questions remain:

- Why is the serializer not generating the xml correctly with a default
  namespace?
- I'd expect an exception if the serializer can't read the data and put it into my instance (why create an "empty" instance)