# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'queryAll' Message:

Tags: c#

Here is my entire CSharp code and the last line of the code is getting the error message.

> ```
>   Here is the Error message back from running my test in Visual Studio.
>
>
>
> Message: 
>     System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException : Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'queryAll'.
>       ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There is an error in XML document (1, 546).
>       ----> System.InvalidOperationException : The specified type was not recognized: name='CARS_Vehicle__c',
> ```

namespace SalesforceTest
{
[Binding]
public class OL_InventorySteps
{
public Stream XmlWriter { get; private set; }

```
    [Given(@"I log into Salesforce")]
    public async Task GivenILogIntoSalesforce()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(XmlSerializer).GetMethod("set_Mode", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1 });

        SoapClient sc = new SoapClient();
        loginRequest req = new loginRequest();
        req.LoginScopeHeader = new LoginScopeHeader();
        string ServerURL;
        string SessionID;

        req.username = "xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mwqa";
        req.password = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        Console.WriteLine(sc.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString());

        loginResponse res = new loginResponse();

        try
        {
            res = await sc.loginAsync(null, req.username, req.password);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

        //Get the ServerURL from the Result
        ServerURL = res.result.serverUrl;
        SessionID = res.result.sessionId;

        queryAllRequest QA_Request = new queryAllRequest();
        SoapClient.EndpointConfiguration EP = new SoapClient.EndpointConfiguration();
        //EP.Equals(ServerURL);
        SoapClient Client = new SoapClient(EP, ServerURL);//, ServerURL);
        SessionHeader SH = new SessionHeader();
        QueryOptions QO = new QueryOptions();
        QO.batchSize = 50;
        QO.batchSizeSpecified = true;
        QA_Request.QueryOptions = QO;

        SH.sessionId = SessionID;
        QA_Request.SessionHeader = SH;

        QA_Request.queryString = "SELECT Account_Number__c, Name, 
        Origination_Country__c, Remarketing_Vehicle_Type__c, Remarketing_Status__c, 
        Hold_Reason__c FROM CARS_Vehicle__c WHERE Account_Number__c = \'xxxxxxxxxxxx\'";

        Console.WriteLine(Client.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString());
        IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
           
        var QA_Response = await Client.queryAllAsync(QA_Request.SessionHeader, 
        QA_Request.QueryOptions, QA_Request.queryString);
```

1. Here is the Xml soap response

   <soapenv:Envelope <xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" <xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" <xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
   soapenv:Header


   16141
   5000000
   API REQUESTS


   </soapenv:Header>
   soapenv:Body


   true


   <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
   <sf:Account_Number__c>XXXXXXXXXXXX</sf:Account_Number__c>
   <sf:Name>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sf:Name>
   <sf:Origination_Country__c>USA</sf:Origination_Country__c>
   <sf:Remarketing_Status__c>Closed</sf:Remarketing_Status__c>
   <sf:Remarketing_Vehicle_Type__c>Retail Repo</sf:Remarketing_Vehicle_Type__c>


   <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
   <sf:Account_Number__c>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</sf:Account_Number__c>
   <sf:Name>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sf:Name>
   <sf:Origination_Country__c>USA</sf:Origination_Country__c>
   <sf:Remarketing_Status__c>Open</sf:Remarketing_Status__c>
   <sf:Remarketing_Vehicle_Type__c>Retail Repo</sf:Remarketing_Vehicle_Type__c>

   2


   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Opening tag is missing for soapenv:Header and soapenv:Body

Comment: Hi Arun Kumar, I updated the post and do have the soapenv:Header and soapenv:Body as well.

Comment: Please look at the following post as it relates to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775320/c-sharp-cant-deserialize-xml-containing-xsitype